# Associations between three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I have Article model which should have one gallery, and every gallery should have many pictures. Associations between Article-Gallery, Gallery-Picture models work properly, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong with Article-Picture association. I've attached my code below.

*Article.rb model*

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :pictures, through: :galleries
end
```

*Gallery.rb model*

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles
end
```

*Picture.rb model*

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :articles, through: :galleries
end
```

*Schema.rb*

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150829181617) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.integer  "language_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
  end

  add_index "articles", ["gallery_id"], name: "index_articles_on_gallery_id"

  create_table "galleries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pictures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the error message you got but I bet you have to change `through: :gallery`. Note the singular.

Comment: @Doguita thank you very much! I don't know how I could miss such a important thing. Change to singular helped here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David's answer is right, `belongs_to` does work for `through` associations in Rails 4.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    has_many :pictures, through: :gallery   # not :galleries
end
```

The thing to remember is that the `through` part of a `has_one` or `has_many` is referring to an **association**, not another **model**. This is important when you're doing trickier associations.

Comment: "... through doesn't work on belongs_to ..." -- not true on Rails 4, at least: see the guides for this exact situation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: The link you posted doesn't actually demonstrate a has_many through a belongs to, but your general statement was correct. I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 4 you can certainly state that an Article:

```
belongs_to :gallery
has_many   :pictures, :through => :gallery
```

... and that a picture ...

```
belongs_to :gallery
has_many   :articles, :through => :gallery
```

... allowing you to do both:

```
@picture.articles
```

... and ...

```
@article.galleries
```

... with both of those being executed as a single query joining through the galleries table.